# Get modified file list in Azure devops pipeline after trigger by commit/push

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline. Right now, the pipeline triggers when a push is made to the branch feat/ENC_CI.

Have plans to later change it so that the pipeline triggers when any branch merges to 'main' branch. Not sure if this will require me to change the yml to fetch modified files.

Right now, it looks like this

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feat/ENV_CI

steps:
  - checkout: self
  - script: |
      echo "Commit ID: $(Build.SourceVersion)"
      changedFiles=$(git diff  --name-only --relative --diff-filter=AM HEAD^ HEAD)
      echo "Files changed: $changedFiles"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedFiles]$changedFiles"
```

No matter what I do, it always result in:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the
> working tree.
>
> fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the
> working tree
>
> fatal: ambiguous argument '@^': unknown revision or path not in the
> working tree.
>
> fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/feat/ENV_CI': unknown revision or
> path not in the working tree.

and others like these resulting from different git commands. WOuld be thankful if someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 2

  - task: Bash@3
    name: ModifiedFiles
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        MODIFIED_FILES=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
        echo $MODIFIED_FILES
```

Azure DevOps's default shallow fetch is 1. Set fetchDepth to 2 to get the list of the files changed since the last commit.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, it works!

Just for curiosity, will I need to change anything if the pipeline is configured to trigger after a feature branch is merged to main branch.

Comment: Perfect. You don't need to make any changes. It'll work for both merge and commit.
(Please don't forget mark the answer is accepted if it works, it'll help others in the community)

Comment: You're the boss. Thanks.